# Show form only in presence of graphics tablet/pen input device?

Tags: wpf, winforms, tablet-pc, pen-tablet

Is there any way that I can show a window only when a pen/tablet is in use, just like the windows tablet PC input panel is only shown when a pen/tablet is used (and not just connected)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle or set a trigger for the `UIElement.StylusInRange` event to make your control visible. (Conversely there is a `StylusOutOfRange` event which you might need for hiding)